# Updated local variables every data change in cloud firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have problem to set my local variables every time the data in cloud firestore. In local variable call `count_vehicle` for example, the value is  count of value with spesific condition based on data in cloud firestore. For examples after run the program the `count_vehicle = 4`, when i changes the data in firestore, the `count_vehicle` variables must 3 after some calculation, but instead the `count_vehicle become 7 (3+4)`. To solve this, my intention is to set `count vehicle = 0` before start calculation. This is my code

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
//import section

//component declaration section



export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  items = any[];
  count_vehicle: number =0;

  constructor(public service: FireService) {
  }
  startAnimationForLineChart(chart){
  ngOnInit() {
      this.service.getVehicle().pipe(     
        map(actions => actions.map(a => {       
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          if(data.value>300){
            this.count_vehicle++;
          }
          return {id, .. data};
        }))
      ) 
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.items = res;       
        console.log(res)
      })

      }
}
```

**fire.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FireService {

  constructor(public db : AngularFirestore) { }

  getVehicle() : Observable<any[]>{
    return this.db.collection('/recent_sensor_data').snapshotChanges()
    }
    }
  }
```

Thanks if you can help.sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a value to reset the counter to the observable with something like:

```
this.service.getVehicle().merge(Rx.Observable.from([ -1*this.count_vehicle ])).pipe(...
```